# two columns column breaks

Tags: line-breaking, two-column

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,BCOR10mm,DIV11,toc=listof,parskip=full]{scrbook}
```

class and two columns there via "\twocolumn".
It works fine mostly but in some instances of the texts involved I have the situation that part of the text of the left column is not put into the next line, and thus seen half into the right column.

Interestingly it seems that there is some connectionn to () there as it always happened with text put in paranthesis. (Body) ,....

Is this a known limitation there that () text is being problematic? And how can I circumvent this problem?

Edit:

AS asked in the comments. As it seems the probblem only happens when something inside () is at the end of a line (in this case "Longevity" reaches into the 2nd column).

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,BCOR10mm,DIV11,toc=listof,parskip=full]{scrbook}

    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{booktabs}            
    \usepackage{multicol}            


    \title{title \\*
           title 2nd part}
    \subtitle{Species book}
    \author{author}
    \date{}

    \begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \newpage

    \tableofcontents
    \twocolumn

    \chapter{chapter}

    \section{section}

    \subsection{Advantages}
    \noindent\textbf{Dragons health}: Dragons regenerate X points of body per hour in their natural form and Y body per hour in their disguised form.
    \textit{Dragons can regenerate wounds (BODY) extremely fast and even regrow limbs. They regenerate the fastest in their natural form.
    The only wounds they are not able to heal at an accelerated rate are wounds taken from unnatural sources like magic or wounds taken from other dragons
    claws, tails, teeth or breathes.}

    \noindent\textbf{blah 1} asdfsdfasfkjsadfkljsd fjasdlfjkasdf jklsdfkljkl
    asfjdklsjfla skfjljkasdlkfjasdklfja sdlfjkasdlfjksdlakjasdkfjasdfasdfjasdklfj
    ajksldfjasdfljasdlfjkasdkljasdlfj asdlfjkasdfkasdj fsdjfsdklfj klasdfj  asdlf asdklj sjkadf asdjklf asdklfjasd asdfas klasdf jkl fjklf lafjlas
     jaskldf sdjlfsljasdlfj aj klasd jfljkflsdlak fasdf sdjklaf sdklf jsfsa

     \noindent\textbf{blah 2} asdfsdfasfkjsadfkljsd fjasdlfjkasdf jklsdfkljkl
    asfjdklsjfla skfjljkasdlkfjasdklfja sdlfjkasdlfjksdlakjasdkfjasdfasdfjasdklfj
    ajksldfjasdfljasdlfjkasdkljasdlfj asdlfjkasdfkasdj fsdjfsdklfj klasdfj  asdlf asdklj sjkadf asdjklf asdklfjasd asdfas klasdf jkl fjklf lafjlas
     jaskldf sdjlfsljasdlfj aj klasd jfljkflsdlak fasdf sdjklaf sdklf jsfsa

     \noindent\textbf{blah 3} asdfsdfasfkjsadfkljsd fjasdlfjkasdf jklsdfkljkl
    asfjdklsjfla skfjljkasdlkfjasdklfja sdlfjkasdlfjksdlakjasdkfjasdfasdfjasdklfj
    ajksldfjasdfljasdlfjkasdkljasdlfj asdlfjkasdfkasdj fsdjfsdklfj klasdfj  asdlf asdklj sjkadf asdjklf asdklfjasd asdfas klasdf jkl fjklf lafjlas
     jaskldf sdjlfsljasdlfj aj klasd jfljkflsdlak fasdf sdjklaf sdklf jsfsa

     \noindent\textbf{blah 4} asdfsdfasfkjsadfkljsd fjasdlfjkasdf jklsdfkljkl
    asfjdklsjfla skfjljkasdlkfjasdklfja sdlfjkasdlfjksdlakjasdkfjasdfasdfjasdklfj
    ajksldfjasdfljasdlfjkasdkljasdlfj asdlfjkasdfkasdj fsdjfsdklfj klasdfj  asdlf asdklj sjkadf asdjklf asdklfjasd asdfas klasdf jkl fjklf lafjlas
     jaskldf sdjlfsljasdlfj aj klasd jfljkflsdlak fasdf sdjklaf sdklf jsfsa

      \noindent\textbf{blah 4} asdfsdfasfkjsadfkljsd fjasdlfjkasdf jklsdfkljkl
    asfjdklsjfla skfjljkasdlkfjasdklfja sdlfjkasdlfjksdlakjasdkfjasdfasdfjasdklfj
    ajksldfjasdfljasdlfjkasdkljasdlfj asdlfjkasdfkasdj fsdjfsdklfj klasdfj  asdlf asdklj sjkadf asdjklf asdklfjasd asdfas klasdf jkl fjklf lafjlas
     jaskldf sdjlfsljasdlfj aj klasd jfljkflsdlak fasdf sdjklaf sdklf jsfsa

      \noindent\textbf{blah 4} asdfsdfasfkjsadfkljsd fjasdlfjkasdf jklsdfkljkl
    asfjdklsjfla skfjljkasdlkfjasdklfja sdlfjkasdlfjksdlakjasdkfjasdfasdfjasdklfj
    ajksldfjasdfljasdlfjkasdkljasdlfj asdlfjkasdfkasdj fsdjfsdklfj klasdfj  asdlf asdklj sjkadf asdjklf asdklfjasd asdfas klasdf jkl fjklf lafjlas
     jaskldf sdjlfsljasdlfj aj klasd jfljkflsdlak fasdf sdjklaf sdklf jsfsa

      \noindent\textbf{blah 4} asdfsdfasfkjsadfkljsd fjasdlfjkasdf jklsdfkljkl
    asfjdklsjfla skfjljkasdlkfjasdklfja sdlfjkasdlfjksdlakjasdkfjasdfasdfjasdklfj
    ajksldfjasdfljasdlfjkasdkljasdlfj asdlfjkasdfkasdj fsdjfsdklfj klasdfj  asdlf asdklj sjkadf asdjklf asdklfjasd asdfas klasdf jkl fjklf lafjlas
     jaskldf sdjlfsljasdlfj aj klasd jfljkflsdlak fasdf sdjklaf sdklf jsfsa

      \noindent\textbf{blah 4} asdfsdfasfkjsadfkljsd fjasdlfjkasdf jklsdfkljkl
    asfjdklsjfla skfjljkasdlkfjasdklfja sdlfjkasdlfjksdlakjasdkfjasdfasdfjasdklfj
    ajksldfjasdfljasdlfjkasdkljasdlfj asdlfjkasdfkasdj fsdjfsdklfj klasdfj  asdlf asdklj sjkadf asdjklf asdklfjasd asdfas klasdf jkl fjklf lafjlas
     jaskldf sdjlfsljasdlfj aj klasd jfljkflsdlak fasdf sdjklaf sdklf jsfsa

    \noindent\textbf{Ageless beings}: +4 CP
    \textit{Life Support (Longevity: Immortal) (5 Active Points); Unified Power (Dragon; -1/4)}


  \noindent\textbf{blah 4} asdfsdfasfkjsadfkljsd fjasdlfjkasdf jklsdfkljkl
asfjdklsjfla skfjljkasdlkfjasdklfja sdlfjkasdlfjksdlakjasdkfjasdfasdfjasdklfj
ajksldfjasdfljasdlfjkasdkljasdlfj asdlfjkasdfkasdj fsdjfsdklfj klasdfj  asdlf asdklj sjkadf asdjklf asdklfjasd asdfas klasdf jkl fjklf lafjlas
 jaskldf sdjlfsljasdlfj aj klasd jfljkflsdlak fasdf sdjklaf sdklf jsfsa


  \noindent\textbf{blah 4} asdfsdfasfkjsadfkljsd fjasdlfjkasdf jklsdfkljkl
asfjdklsjfla skfjljkasdlkfjasdklfja sdlfjkasdlfjksdlakjasdkfjasdfasdfjasdklfj
ajksldfjasdfljasdlfjkasdkljasdlfj asdlfjkasdfkasdj fsdjfsdklfj klasdfj  asdlf asdklj sjkadf asdjklf asdklfjasd asdfas klasdf jkl fjklf lafjlas
 jaskldf sdjlfsljasdlfj aj klasd jfljkflsdlak fasdf sdjklaf sdklf jsfsa


  \noindent\textbf{blah 4} asdfsdfasfkjsadfkljsd fjasdlfjkasdf jklsdfkljkl
asfjdklsjfla skfjljkasdlkfjasdklfja sdlfjkasdlfjksdlakjasdkfjasdfasdfjasdklfj
ajksldfjasdfljasdlfjkasdkljasdlfj asdlfjkasdfkasdj fsdjfsdklfj klasdfj  asdlf asdklj sjkadf asdjklf asdklfjasd asdfas klasdf jkl fjklf lafjlas
 jaskldf sdjlfsljasdlfj aj klasd jfljkflsdlak fasdf sdjklaf sdklf jsfsa


  \noindent\textbf{blah 4} asdfsdfasfkjsadfkljsd fjasdlfjkasdf jklsdfkljkl
asfjdklsjfla skfjljkasdlkfjasdklfja sdlfjkasdlfjksdlakjasdkfjasdfasdfjasdklfj
ajksldfjasdfljasdlfjkasdkljasdlfj asdlfjkasdfkasdj fsdjfsdklfj klasdfj  asdlf asdklj sjkadf asdjklf asdklfjasd asdfas klasdf jkl fjklf lafjlas
 jaskldf sdjlfsljasdlfj aj klasd jfljkflsdlak fasdf sdjklaf sdklf jsfsa


  \noindent\textbf{blah 4} asdfsdfasfkjsadfkljsd fjasdlfjkasdf jklsdfkljkl
asfjdklsjfla skfjljkasdlkfjasdklfja sdlfjkasdlfjksdlakjasdkfjasdfasdfjasdklfj
ajksldfjasdfljasdlfjkasdkljasdlfj asdlfjkasdfkasdj fsdjfsdklfj klasdfj  asdlf asdklj sjkadf asdjklf asdklfjasd asdfas klasdf jkl fjklf lafjlas
 jaskldf sdjlfsljasdlfj aj klasd jfljkflsdlak fasdf sdjklaf sdklf jsfsa


    \end{document}
```

*Also as it could be important: I'm using writelatex.com there to write the document (although not sure if it is only limited to there or a general latex phenomenon.*

Comment: You should really show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv), since this could be related to the content included inside the `()`.

Comment: put up an excerpt there tnx

Comment: @ThomasE. A MWE is a little bit more than an *excerpt* ;-)

Comment: would that be enough or should enough text be added that the multi column takes effect? (those are 2 text locations where the phenomenon happens)

Comment: @ThomasE: Well, it is not complete so far ;-)

Comment: tnx (whoever delted his comment again helped me there). put up a whole example I just made.  interestingly in that example BODY was displayed in the next line instead of the same line as in the original case.  

what is also interesting is if I put a blank between ( and longevity it is put into the next line longevity I mean there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will see the problem replicated with/without `()`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,BCOR10mm,DIV11,toc=listof,parskip=full]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\twocolumn

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{Ageless beings}: +4 CP
\textit{Life Support (Longevity: Immortal) (5 Active Points); Unified Power (Dragon; -1/4)}

\noindent\textbf{Ageless beings}: +4 CP
\textit{Life Support Longevity: Immortal (5 Active Points); Unified Power (Dragon; -1/4)}

\end{document}
```

Since you're most likely going to use `longevity` quite a lot in this document, add

```
\hyphenation{lon-gev-i-ty}
```

to your document preamble. It will add the [hyphenation pattern for `longevity`](https://www.google.ca/webhp?q=longevity%20meaning#q=longevity+meaning) to the list of existing hyphenations:

[image]

Note that you may still receive overfull `\hbox` warnings, which depend on your paragraph construction. Typically these are removed when reformatting the paragraph text, perhaps using `\raggedright` or even including [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype).

Here is an example with full justification (top) and `\raggedright` (bottom):

[image]

Comment: and what can be done in the case of (BODY)? 
In the original text it had the same problem.

Comment: @ThomasE.: What about attempting a `\raggedright` document layout? Columns are very narrow with your settings, making it difficult to find sufficient spacing to correct the layout. `\raggedright` will break a line if the subsequent word doesn't fit. The [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package provides similar functionality *with* hyphenation support.

Comment: raggedright corrected the problem tnx